# Using regex and matching whole pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have two strings

> ('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth')
>
> ('first', 'second', 'third', 'fifth')

and through this pattern I want to match both of them, problem is that when I run `preg_match` on one of the strings then I get match for the whole string but also just for the `('fourth'|'fifth')` part. So the result is

```
array(
[0]=>
    array(
          [0]=>('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth')
          [1]=>0
    )
[1]=>
    array(
          [0]=>'fourth'
          [1]=>29
    )
)
```

Is there a way to not take into account just the single world after `or` condition ?

```
preg_match("/\"place=\('first', 'second', 'third', ('fourth'|'fifth')\);\"/",
        $string, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Why is it a problem that you have another group?

Comment: So you just want to exclude that second match? If so, you can make it a non-matching group `(?:'fourth'|'fifth')`

Comment: That worked, thanks!... It is a problem because I want to match both of these strings in one string and then use their indexes, so that second match would be confusing because I would need to know filter out unwanted matches